# MySQL left join problem

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sQuery = '
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS IF( `Profiles`.`Couple`=0,
`Profiles`.`ID`, IF( `Profiles`.`Couple`>`Profiles`.`ID`, `Profiles`.`ID`,
`Profiles`.`Couple` ) ) AS `ID` FROM `Profiles`';


$sCountries = implode("','", $mValue);
    $sJoin .= " LEFT JOIN `hm_locations` ON (`hm_locations`.`country` IN '".$sCountries."' 
    AND `hm_locations`.`profileID` = `Profiles`.`ID`) ";
```

This query is gathered different functions then is put together with another function, but I basically want to know how I could re-write the LEFT JOIN section to work properly.

I'm trying to add on my own left join here so that the search will grab IDs from hm_locations where the country matches the search.

I only want help with the LEFT JOIN section because that's the only part not working.

Thanks alot

Comment: The actual error message you're encountering would be very helpful to figure out what's going on, as would an example of the plain SQL, as run as a test in phpMyAdmin, for example.

Comment: if you need help with SQL, post SQL code, not PHP, silly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your countries in parenthesis:

```
"... `hm_locations`.`country` IN ('".$sCountries."') ..."
```

Comment: It's true - IN() is a function.  Also, are the values in $mValue escaped already?  They really should be.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL LEFT JOIN Syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
LEFT JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

I don't see anything allowed other than an "=" clause based on values in the tables, in your case Profiles and hm_locations. The "IN" clause with the "AND" is not part of the syntax for LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use w3schools as the final arbiter of correct SQL syntax.